# How to add another prop to ...props in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router and I've created a PrivateRoute component that shows the component if authenticated, otherwise redirects to the login page.

What I want to do is pass an additional prop (authentication) on top of the ones specified by the caller.

I can't seem to get the syntax right, and googling for "...props" didn't bring up any documentation.

Here's my code:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
            <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
                this.state.authentication.authenticated() ? (
                    <Component authentication:{this.state.authentication} {...props}/>
                ) : (
                    <Redirect to={{
                        pathname: '/login',
                        state: { from: props.location }
                    }}/>
                )
            )}/>
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with `authentication` prop syntax. Use `=` instead of `:`

```
<Component authentication={this.state.authentication} {...props}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be a prop just like any other:

```
<Component
  authentication={this.state.authentication}
  {...props}
/>
```

I find it helps to put them on separate lines to easily see what's happening.

Also, if `{...props}` already contains a key called `authentication`, then you can override it by putting it after:

```
const someProps = {
  hello: 1
};

// this.props.hello will be 2
<Component
  {...someProps}
  hello={2}
/>
```